# Out-Host -Paging error "The method or operation is not implemented. " (ISE)

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I execute this Powershell command:

```
Get-Process | Out-Host -Paging
```

But it returns me error:

> ut-lineoutput : The method or operation is not implemented.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-Process | Out-Host -Paging
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [out-lineoutput], NotImplementedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotImplementedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand

I have checked help for Out-host and with paging it should be returnig results page by page.

Basically I want to see results page by page not everythign flush. Please help

Comment: PowerShell ISE doesn't support paging

Answer (score 4):

The `-Paging` flag doesn't work for `powershell_ise.exe`.

Use `powershell.exe`

Another option though it may not be exactly what you need...

```
$file="c:\temp\out.txt"
dir -Recurse | Out-File $file
notepad $file
```

Comment: I need to use ISE, what I should use in ISE for paging please ?

Comment: I've searched on Google and ISE doesn't support paging.  Some other options are to do | Out-File or | Out-GridView - but it's not exactly the same

Comment: "I need to use ISE" - why?

Comment: @user576510 Pipe to `more.com`: `Get-Process | more`

Answer (score 0):

to paginate, you could do this...

```
$page = 20
$step = $page
$command = get-process
$count = $command.count
while ($count -gt ($page - $step)){
    $command[($page - $step)..$page]
    Pause
    $page += $step + 1
}
```

Just set $page to whatever you want to see per page ... it's actually 1 more than you'd like because you start with 0 NOT 1. so 20 will show 21 per page.

some one turned this into a module, so you could do that...
http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-more-in-the-powershell-ise

his script basically reads each line individually, then if you hit your counter, it just spits out "press enter to continue" then reads the next line etc...