# PowerShell command pipe line that will pause during get-Childitem -Recurse

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I was auditing all file content on users and is using the PowerShell command to get childitems but would like to see the options that will pause the results and wait for me to press any key to continue.

Get-Childitem -Recurse |

Comment: Do you mean pause mid way through a `Get-ChildItem` or after it gathers the data?

Comment: There are some interesting answers here. Based on the thinking that piping Linux commands to `more` or `less` is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078920/equivalent-of-more-or-less-command-in-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PowerShell Command Line

In PowerShell Command Line you can pipe your command through `more` or `Out-Host -Paging`

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Out-Host -Paging

#Alias version
gci -rec | oh -Paging
```

Each page will show with the last line as:

```
<SPACE> next page; <CR> next line; Q quit
```

Allowing you to page through the output.

### PowerShell ISE

This link gives more information, it seems like it is not possible in the scripting environment: [Out-Host -Paging error "The method or operation is not implemented. " (ISE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231528/out-host-paging-error-the-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented-ise)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply - this is the one I've been looking for.